# Angular UI router nested views not showing anything

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been through several similar questions here on this and still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am looking to load a view within a view (which also happens to be within another view).

The code in `rules.html` is not appearing. Am I misunderstanding the concepts behind ui-router?

In the firefox developer console I am simply getting `<!-- uiView: rules -->`

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="App">
   <div class="container" ui-view="container" ></div>
</body>
```

**parent.html**

```
<div>
    //some wrapper stuff
    <div ui-view="parent"></div>
</div>
```

**edit-entity.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ProjectManagerController as data">
        // other code showing fine
        <div ui-view="rules"></div>
        // other code showing fine
</div>
```

**rules.html**

```
<div>TEST CODE</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        views: {
            'container': {
                templateUrl: 'views/parent.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
                controller: 'MainController as data'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('edit-entity', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/entity/{id:int}/edit',
        views: {
            'parent': {
                templateUrl: 'views/entity-edit.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
                controller: 'MainController as main'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('rules', {
        parent: 'edit-entity',
        views: {
            'rules': {
                templateUrl: 'views/rules.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
                controller: 'MainController as data'
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT: I have also tried `rules.entity`

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to trace the path in a nested state from the parent state.
Edit: I have added a Plunker for your work: http://plnkr.co/edit/mBYdUTEkaLsqhI6MNW4I?p=preview

```
.state('app', {
  views: {
      'container': {
          templateUrl: 'views/parent.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
          controller: 'MainController as data'
      },
      'container.parent@app': {
          templateUrl: 'views/entity-edit.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
          controller: 'MainController as main'
      }
      'container.parent.rules@app': {
          templateUrl: 'views/rules.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
          controller: 'MainController as data'
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but are you sure this is fully correct? Im a bit lost as to why `edit-entity` is a parent of `app` and also not sure where this order is coming from `container.parent.rules.edit-entity`, should it not be  `container.parent.edit-entity.rules`?

Comment: @Adrian so sorry the parent was a typo.  I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this works -

```
.state('rules', {
    parent: 'edit-entity',
    views: {
        'rules@edit-entity': {
            templateUrl: 'views/rules.html?nd=' + Date.now(),
            controller: 'MainController as data'
        }
    }
});
```

I just added the '@' after the view name (absolute naming). You can read more here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names. I've found that this works for me sometimes.

Comment: thanks for the help but unfortunately no joy. I had tried something like that earlier alright. Very strange!